# How to move values from a CSV file to a float array?

Tags: c, arrays, file, csv

I have a `.csv` file formatted like this:

```
24.74,2.1944,26.025,7.534,9.317,0.55169 [etc]
```

I want to move the float values into a floating point number array.

The array would look like this:

```
fValues[0] = 24.74
fValues[1] = 2.1944
fValues[2] = 26.025
fValues[3] = 7.534
fValues[4] = 9.317
[etc]
```

I have 1000 numbers to process.

What is the code to achieve this task?

This is the closest I have gotten with my code:

```
int main()
{
  FILE *myFile;

  float fValues[10000];
  int n,i = 0;

  myFile = fopen("es2.csv", "r");
  if (myFile == NULL) {
    printf("failed to open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  while (fscanf(myFile, "%f", &fValues[n++]) != EOF);

  printf("fValues[%d]=%f\n", i, fValues[5]); //index 5 to test a number is there.

  fclose(myFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Also, when I run this code I receive exit code `3221224725`.

Would this be a memory access related issue/stack overflow)?

My environment:

- Sublime Text 3,
- GCC compiler,
- Newer windows laptop

Comment: You have comas in your file. Nothing in your program accounts for them. You cannot pretend they are not there.

Comment: `n++` - Hmmm. And what was `n` before that loop was entered? If your answer is "I dunno" you're in agreement with your program, because it doesn't know either. You never set it's initial value. Your program invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read from the file, you're not skipping over the commas in the file.

The first call to `fscanf` reads a `float` via the `%f` format specifier.  On subsequent reads, the file pointer is at the first comma and doesn't go past that because you're still trying to read a floating point number.

You need to add a separate call to `fscanf` inside the loop to consume the comma:

```
while (fscanf(myFile, "%f", &fValues[n++]) == 1) {
  fscanf(myFile, ",");
}
```

Also, you're not initializing `n`:

```
int n,i = 0;
```

When you then attempt to increment it, thereby reading an uninitialized value, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Initialize it like this:

```
int n = 0, i = 0;
```